# Не позиционируется v-container во vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify

Не получается спозиционировать v-container по центру оси x, класс который в документации не срабатывает(

```
  <v-container class="mx-auto">
    <v-row>
      <v-col cols="3" class="pa-0">
        <v-text-field dark label="Например ZCash" v-model.trim="ticker" />
      </v-col>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Он срабатывает, но значение `auto` у левого и правого маржинов имеет эффект только если ширина элемента с таким стилем меньше ширины родительского. Плюс, стоит проверить возможное перекрытие значения `margin` другими стилями (несмотря на то что стиль утилити-класса содержит `!important`, его все-таки возможно перекрыть).

Comment: @yar85 проверил, родитель больше дочернего контайнера, но он все равно не центрируется по центру через my-auto(

Comment: Значит, либо перекрытие значения `margin`, либо есть стили которые делают маржин неэффективным (например, те которые вырывают элемент `v-container`'а из потока документа). Причина есть так или иначе, чудес же не бывает... но по скриншоту не увидеть вычисленных стилей, так что тебе на выбор 2 варианта: либо самостоятельно искать эту причину, либо добавлять в вопрос запускаемый минимальный пример с проблемой (чтобы сообщество в поиске причины помогло).

Answer (score 0):

В тексте вы хотите выровнять по оси х а на картинке по оси у, уточните ось по которой выравниваете если по оси у:

```
<v-container class="my-auto">
```